# How to Create a Jar file in Spring boot with Data Source that is not live?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've configured properties file with data source i.e URL of a database, and credentials of **some other System** since I need to build executable jar and and deploy the application  into that System and it is not accessible.

Since the URL is different it's not remotely accessible, when I try to build, exception is occurring since it's looking for configuring live database which is not existed.

So, I want to build and create executable jar file. But data source isn't live in my system. But It's going to be once I deploy the jar into another system.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you use to build? maven or gradle?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Maven

Comment: Try `mvn package`

Comment: I did using mvnw clean package, this is where I'm not able to build the jar. Getting exception.

Comment: which exception do you get? btw I would use `mvn clean package`. If the problem is concerning test compiling add `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` to your command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two properties, `application-development.properties`, for development configuration,  and `application-production.properties`, for live configuration.

To create a jar, use `mvn clean install`.

After that go to the target folder and use below command to run the jar file

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active= production YourJarFileName.jar  // if you want to run live database
```

Comment: Seems it makes sense. Let me implement this and get back to you.